# How to prevent pip install without virtualenv?

Tags: virtualenv, pip

I really hate running something like `make` and then be surprised by pip installing a load of packages because I forgot to activate my virtualenv.

Is there any way to force pip to prompt / warn me that I'm not in *some* virtualenv?

Comment: delete your pip in global maybe?

Comment: How about ~/.virtualenvrc ? Add source ~/.bashrc; source ~/python-projects/virtualenv/activate

Comment: @CodeGroover, my point is that I want to prevent accidentally polluting my global environment with a ton of packages

Comment: @Mikhail reuse e.g. bash wrapper

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Taken from http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/pip-virtualenv/

You need to set a environmental variable `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV`

Best practice would be to place it in your autostart file (`.bash_profile` or similar)

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

To install the package globally, you can then run `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip ...` or create a command `gpip`, also in the autostart file:

```
gpip() {
    PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can enforce this by passing a flag to `pip`:

```bash
python3 -m pip --require-virtualenv install <some-package>
```

Or by setting a configuration option:

```bash
python3 -m pip config set global.require-virtualenv True
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a note that pip version 20.2.3 from Python 3.6 requires `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false` rather than `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=""` to install global dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gotten in the habit of never typing `sudo` beforehand and follow up critical commands with `sudo !!` then you can do this script to follow up restricted pip commands with `pipdo !!`

`--user` is used to not clobber you global install (which is also the reason that we use PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV [What is the purpose "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

More explanation of why you may want install without an virtualenv, but you still may want to protect yourself against install into your system python. https://github.com/zchee/deoplete-jedi/wiki/Setting-up-Python-for-Neovim#simple-setup

```bash
# don't let pip work without using virtualenvs
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
# allow to overcome the above with pipdo !!
function pipdo {
    case "$@" in
      *install*--user*)
        PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false $@
        ;;
      *install*)
        echo 'Remember to `pip install --user`'
        ;;
      *)
        PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false $@
        ;;
    esac
}
```