# Permission denied on DESCRIPTION.rst file when trying to PIP uninstall a package in order to upgrade it

Tags: python, permissions, pip

Am getting a "Permission denied" error pertaining to a file named  DESCRIPTION.rst while trying to PIP uninstall a package in order to upgrade it.

I originally ran this command:

```
pip uninstall twilio
```

There was a lot of output, but the important stuff was:

```
...
...
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/version.pyc
Proceed (y/n)? y
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 59, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1035, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio-3.6.6.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/chris/.pip/pip.log
[chris@boogie-dev ~]$
```

I'm not really sure how I should go about solving this problem. I don't understand PIP too well, or the ins and outs of python library pakcages, or what a DESCRIPTION.rst file is and why it is there with special permissions.

I already tried the command under `sudo`, however PIP is not available under `sudo`. I'm not sure what is the correct angle to take on this problem:

- Install pip under the sudo account and then try to uninstall using the sudo account - which is not the same account that was using to originally install the package
- Delete the `DESCRIPTION.rst` file while using sudo
- Some other, more elegant approach that I'm not aware of

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading `modules` from `python.org` you can download modules using `pip`, but while doing this you should be in `root mode`.

First when you are running

```
root@achal-PC:~# apt-get install python-pip
...it will install pip tool...

root@achal-PC:~# which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

next when you are installing `twilio` as

```
root@achal-PC:~# pip install twilio
..Successfully installed twilio PyJWT pytz...
```

Instead of `un-install` do `upgrade` there itself as

```
root@achal-PC:~# pip install --upgrade twilio
Requirement already up-to-date: twilio in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up..
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. Try with `--user` flag, like this: `pip uninstall --user twilio`.

While in my case it *didn't* change the location of where my package was installed / uninstalled, my guess is that it avoids touching some files that are reserved for root access. More info in this question: [What is the purpose "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)