# Pip install python package for current user

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Recently I delete some files related to `python 2.7` and now I'm crazy. I want to use `pip` to install python package for current user rather global user.

```
➜  ~ where pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

➜  ~ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

In the past, I can install `requests` easily by `pip install requests`. But now I have to `sudo pip install requests` or `pip install --user requests`.

I think because of pip's location I have to install python package within `/Library/Python/2.7/....`. As you see, it needs root permission. I know `venv` can  help me but now I want to know how to intall python package for current user.

Comment: `--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

Comment: @MortenB I updated my question just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pip`'s `--user` option:

```
pip install --user package
```

According to [`pip`'s documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options):

> `--user`
>
> Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%Python on Windows. (See the Python documentation for site.USER_BASE for full details.)