# Command not found error for deepspeech if installed with user flag

Tags: linux, nlp, ubuntu-16.04, mozilla-deepspeech

I installed deepspeech in ubuntu 16.04 using

`pip install deepspeech --user`

but when I use deepspeech `deepspeech -h` on cli it says command not found.

I have tried both pip and pip3 for installation, also tried restarting but it still says command not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing with pip --user flag, installs the package in the user directory rather than the root directory.
Ex: /Users/.../Library/Python/2.7/bin

**Run**: `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/.../Library/Python/2.7/bin`

and add the above command to your `~/.bash_profile`

**Reference:**
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

Answer (score 3):

I used `pip3 install deepspeech` on my WSL Linux 20.04 and it was installing deepspeech in my home/user/.local/bin directory.

Instead try using `sudo pip3 install deepspeech`. This fixes the problem.