# Could not install packages due to a "Environment error :[error 13]: permission denied : 'usr/local/bin/f2py'"

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I am trying to install numpy on macOS X but after executing the command `pip install numpy` I am getting the error:

> Environment error :[error 13]: permission denied : 'usr/local/bin/f2py

How do I fix it?

Comment: You could install Anaconda, which includes Numpy

Answer (score 162):

This worked for me.

```sh
pip3 install --user package-name  # for Python3
pip install --user package-name   # for Python2
```

The `--user` flag tells Python to install in the user home directory. By default it will go to system locations. [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989020/1756430)

Answer (score 32):

```
pip install --user package-name
```

Seems to work, but the package is install the the path of user. such as :

> "c:\users\***\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-tracker-_akmzo\42a6c7d627641b148564ff35597ec30fd5543aa1cf6e41118b98d7a3"

I want to install the package in python folder such c:\Python27. I install the module into the expected folder by:

```
pip install package-name --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: this is not related. OP is asking about MacOS

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't have MacOS. But it did wrok and solve similar problem in WinOS

Answer (score 12):

I am also a Windows user. And I have installed Python 3.7 and when I try to install any package it throws the same error that you are getting.

Try this out. This worked for me.

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

And whenever you install new package just write

```
python -m pip install <package_name>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 11):

I too had to face the same problem. This worked for me. Right click and run as admin than run usual command to install. But first run update command to update the pip

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 5):

Well, in my case the problem had a different cause, the Windows path Length [Check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows)

I was installing a library on a `virtualenv` which made the path get longer. As the library was installed, it created some files under `site-packages`. This made the path exceed Windows limit throwing this error.

Hope it helps someone =)

Answer (score 3):

As a windows user, run an ***Admin*** powershell and launch :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran the command with sudo:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Bear in mind that you will be asked for the user's password.
This was tested on macOS High Sierra (10.13)

Comment: I have the same problem but with flask package. when I add sudo the package check /usr/local/lib path. but I wanted to install my packages on my virtual env

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for different package. I was installing `pyinstaller` in conda on Mac Mojave. I did

```
conda create --name ai37 python=3.7
conda activate ai37
```

I got the mentioned error when I tried to install pyinstaller using

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

I was able to install the pyinstaller with the following command

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using an virtual env on ubuntu and if you get this error,then navigate to your virtual env folder.If you see a lock symbol like:

[image: folder created with root priviledge]

Then you don't have the appropriate permission as a user to pip install inside this.Hence change the permission of the venv folder using this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER path/to/venv
```

Now switch to the venv and install your package.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows this has worked for me. From the command line, specify the path to the exe for Python:
& "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade pip --user

Answer (score 0):

It is always preferred to use a virtual environment ,Create your virtual environment using :

**`python -m venv <name_of_virtualenv>`**

go to your environment directory and activate your environment using below command on windows:

**`env_name\Scripts\activate.bat`**

then simply use

**`pip install package_name`**