# Why cannot I pip install a Python3 package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, boilerpipe

I am new to Python (3) using Windows 10, 64. When trying to install a package, I get the long error message pasted below. What should I do?

```
(base) C:\Users\xxx>pip install boilerpipe-py3
Collecting boilerpipe-py3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/17/b12ff7b89512fdeea10ec907f871e20ca44961c8d7dd90dc642af573a9e1/boilerpipe-py3-1.2.0.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ugusa_2c\boilerpipe-py3\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
        download_jars(datapath=DATAPATH)
      File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ugusa_2c\boilerpipe-py3\setup.py", line 26, in download_jars
        urlretrieve(tgz_url, tgz_name)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
        with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ugusa_2c\boilerpipe-py3\
```

---

I also tried the following:
`pip install --upgrade pip`.
I got a long error message for that as well, ending with

```
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.1
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\xxx\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\RECORD'
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you possibly are having issues with set up tools. Try `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and include which version you want it to install to. Personally if I had to recommend working with multiple versions of python like it seems you are I'd go with conda environments in pycharm. Lot less issues when working on multiple python versions

Comment: **May have already been solved here:** -----
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807507/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environment-error-error-13-permission-d Check it out

Comment: have you tried pip3?

Answer (score 0):

I think the package have a problem because I have same error when I tried

Concerning updating pip the command is this :

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The package tries to download https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/boilerpipe/boilerpipe-1.2.0.0-bin.tar.gz but the server does not allow access to the file.

You should take the issue to the package maintainer.