# Downloaded 3.8 but terminal is showing as 2.7 and unable to download Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I already downloaded Python 3.8 onto my iOS macbook computer. My terminal is showing me instead that i have 2.7 install instead.

[image: Version here]

Another problem was when downloading python flask, i've gotten this error many times.

[image: Flask Download error.]

Im trying to use python flask on version 3.8 but it keeps registering as 2.7. any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please copy/paste the *text* of the errors you are getting into your question post. Please **do not** post images of the errors!

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `python3`. `python` defaults to version 2.

You can alias `python` to `python3`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Evgeny Bovykin answer

You can find the answer to your second issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50893981/8692977

> ```
> pip3 install --user package-name  # for Python3
> pip install --user package-name   # for Python2
> ```

Comment: You can choose best answer if that solved your issue :)