# New Python version not recognised. I installed the new python version but I get an Error when I try to install packages

Tags: python

I tried to install 'youtube_dl' using

```
pip install youtube_dl
```

And I got an Error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained
after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. 

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_dl-2020.1.24.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I don't understand this because I do have the newest version of Python installed.

Thank you

Comment: The first part is just a warning. The second part shows you do not have sufficient admin rights to perform the installation.

Comment: Clearly you're just using the wrong version of Python, right? Are you not using any virtual environments?

Answer (score 1):

Python deprecation message is just a warning, so like these posts says: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916143/6796652) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50893981/6796652), you need to user `--user` flag, so try with this:

```
pip install youtube_dl --user
```

Remember to active first you virtualenv