# How to Install Pip right?

Tags: python, pip

I tried to begin to program a discord Bot with Python.
When I tried to use this command: python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
to install pip it gives me this Error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multidict-4.7.5.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

When I tried the "pip install --upgrade pip" command it prints he couldnt find the command "Pip"
I dont know what to do and for Information:
Im on MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.4

Thanks to the Helpers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to a "Environment error :\[error 13\]: permission denied : 'usr/local/bin/f2py'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807507/could-not-install-packages-due-to-a-environment-error-error-13-permission-d)

Comment: Welcome to the confusing world of Python! Are you using a virtual environment, usually a solid way to go about making sure you do not mess up permissions I recommend pipenv.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

This worked for me. The normal way doesn't work because you have installed python and pip with it only for user.

Answer (score 0):

an use `pip install's --user` option to install packages into your home directory where you have all required permissions. E.g.:

```
pip install install -U discord.py --user
```