# getting EnvironmentError when running Pip Install beautifulsoup4 on Win10

Tags: python, pip

while installing a python packet on the win10 machine i get fancy messages from the system!?

note - wanted to install bs4 (beautifulSoup) a python packet via pip

```
C:\Users\Kasper>pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

C:\Users\Kasper>pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

C:\Users\Kasper>pip install beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/a1/c698cf319e9cfed6b17376281bd0efc6bfc8465698f54170ef60a485ab5d/beautifulsoup4-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (106kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 2.1MB/s
Collecting soupsieve>=1.2 (from beautifulsoup4)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/cf/ea245e52f55823f19992447b008bcbb7f78efc5960d77f6c34b5b45b36dd/soupsieve-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: soupsieve, beautifulsoup4
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'c:\\program files\\python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\soupsieve'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\Kasper>
```

Is there some thing wrong with the permissions!?

I thought that i have full admin-rights on this machine (wich runs in my office)

any ideas - look forward for any and all help.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong but things I would try: navigating to the python directory in command line and running it again, also try running with the -m command, i.e "python.exe -m pip install beautifulsoup4", also perhaps try upgrading pip?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to a "Environment error :\[error 13\]: permission denied : 'usr/local/bin/f2py'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807507/could-not-install-packages-due-to-a-environment-error-error-13-permission-d)

Comment: You shouldn't be running full admin all the time. In fact, you would need to do a few things differently to do that.

When you go to open up your console right-click on it and 'run as admin' and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you open your command prompt as Administrator and run it again.

If you want to install the package just for the current user, try using --user flag

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 --user
```