# Python module: installing requests in command line terminal inside Atom

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, installation

I tried doing the process I explained in the title, and even using the user-- method I cannot get it to install or find anything.  I tried both later versions and the newer versions of the requests module in python.

Before this I tried without user and it had some error involving the fact that I had Python 2.7.

Thanks to all

[image]

Comment: paste code as text is better than image.

Comment: Please post code as code, instead of images, that makes it harder because no one wants to type the exact same thing as the image, they want to just copy it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `--user Anthony Karrick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try

`pip install --user requests`

instead of `Anthony` type `--user`

--user makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989020/4414156

Bonus Tip: if you are using Atom, or for the sake of any editor and you are using PYTHON, you must use virtual environments. It will keep your packages clean and prevent conflict.

https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-virtualenv