# No module named tensorflow even after installing with pip

Tags: tensorflow, pip, python-3.6

I'm trying to follow this guide to test this new algorithm: https://github.com/lalonderodney/SegCaps

I can't do it in my PC, so i'm using another server with Putty. Now I'm connected with the other server.

First of all I installed TensorFlow as indicates in the guide with :
pip install -r requirements.txt

After I wrote this code: ./main.py segcaps.png 
in which segcaps.png is the image that i want to use

Finally I wrote python main.py --data_root_dir data 
that is the only required parameter with the directory containing imgs and masks folders.

Now it gives me an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.framework'

I searched it in the directory tensorflow/python/framework and it exists.

So, i don't know how to solve it. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple Python versions installed, then you'll (most likely) have multiple `pip` versions installed too. Make sure that the `pip` command you use installs the package(s) into the Python version you want it to. It may so happen that the package got installed into `python2` but you wanted it in `python3`.

Since using `pip` did not install the packages in `python3`, `pip3` is most likely to the PyPI for python3. Try

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

and that should work.

In case you have an **EnvironmentError** you can try this *(bad idea)*:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user
```

This solves the problem most of the times on standalone machines. I'm not sure about the server; insufficient permissions might block this.

> *Why is the **--user** flag a bad idea?* Read: [What is the purpose “pip install --user …”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip show tensorflow` to see if it is installed or not.
As for `ModuleNotFoundError` try uninstalling keras and reinstalling an earlier version by `pip install keras==2.1.6`