# pyodbc module install locally in unix

Tags: python, pyodbc, python-2.6

I am trying to install pyodbc for python 2.6. 
The problem is I am not having admin access to install this module using pip. Is there a possibility to install into a local folder and use by setting the python path or some other way.

Comment: Is the pip issue due to an external connection or is pip itself blocked?

Comment: pip has a `--user` option you could try.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user

Comment: Problem is pip itself is blocked due to firewall settings which I am not having access to change. Tried downloading the package, but running setup.py is giving error as it is not run as root

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Downloaded `pyodbc-4.0.24.tar.gz` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#files) and saved it in my `~/Downloads` folder.

Opened a Terminal window, did `cd ~/Downloads` to switch to the Downloads folder, and then did

```
pip install --user pyodbc-4.0.24.tar.gz
```