# Can't install any package - EnvironmentError [Errno 2]

Tags: python

I've got the following message when trying to install a package with 'pip install slackclient':

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\valadao\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml-0.15.71.dist-info\METADATA'

I have tried to do 'conda install tqdm' but I get '# All requested packages already installed.'

Also tried to do 'pip install ruamel.yaml' but I get the same error:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\valadao\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml-0.15.71.dist-info\METADATA'

Tried a different package ('pip install pdfminer.six') and again the same error:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\valadao\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml-0.15.71.dist-info\METADATA'

Comment: Relevant [what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user/42989020#42989020)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. However, mine is in a Virtualenv, and I thought the point of a virtualenv was to not have to install it as `--user`.

Comment: Already answered here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672097/no-such-file-or-directory-opt-anaconda3-lib-python3-8-site-packages-requests/67672098#67672098](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672097/no-such-file-or-directory-opt-anaconda3-lib-python3-8-site-packages-requests/67672098#67672098)