# Python Import Argparse From Path

Tags: python, import, argparse

I have a pythonscript that imports argparse 
but since i dont have install priviledges I want to know if I can do someting like
import argparse from path /path/to/argparse

Is this possible?
IM new to python

WHEN I RUN THE SCRIPT IT SAYS ARGPARSE IS MISSING
USING: Python 2.6.6
I CANT INSTALL PIP BECAUSE I DONT HAVE SUDO RIGHTS

Comment: `argparse` is part of the standard Python distribution.  You shouldn't need a special install or path.

Comment: hpaulj is correct, you should just "import argparse".

Comment: WHEN I RUN IT 
IT SAYS PACKAGE ARGPARSE IS NOT AVAILABLE

Comment: Please don't shout

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.6.6 I Am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argparse module was added to python in version 2.7, see the official documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

To use it in python 2.6 you can download/install a compatible version using pip, run the following command in the console/terminal (bash, cmd, etc. not python interpreter):

```
pip install argparse
```

To install pip, have a look at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.
Check the python 2.6 specific instructions.

If you don't have root access this thread should help:

[What is the purpose "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

**Alternative solution:**

1. Download the argparse-module from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ThomasWaldmann/argparse/master/argparse.py (linked from pypi)
2. Place it in the same folder as the script requiring argparse

Comment: So can I import it from a path? like

Comment: No, you need to install argparse. After that the error "argparse is missing" should disappear. I have clarified the answer a bit regarding that

Comment: I DONT HAVE SUDO RIGHTS TO INSTALL FROMPIP

Comment: @Bornvs.Me Writing in all caps is considered shouting. Please don't do it.

Comment: @Bornvs.Me Skip the caps-lock routine, otherwise the people who wants to help you will drop to zero very quickly...

Comment: @Bornvs.Me I updated the answer again with a link that should help