# from PIL import Image, ImageTk ImportError: cannot import name ImageTk

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2018.2.4 community edition on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have started python 2.7 project and using the IDE settings -> Project Interpreter I have installed Pillow but whenever I try:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

I get the following error:

> from PIL import Image, ImageTk
>        ImportError: cannot import name ImageTk

how to fix this?

Comment: What's the PIL version?

Comment: @Alderven checking pycharm installed packages I see Package: Pillow Version: 5.1.0

Comment: @Alderven updating it solved the problem thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed it correctly?

`apt-get install python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk`

Comment: no I did not use terminal commands I used pycharm to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply update your Pillow version to the latest for example PIL 7.0.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First become a root user by typing

```
$ sudo su
```

then use this command

```
$ apt-get install python3-pil python3-pil.imaget
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in raspberry pi:

```
$ sudo pip3 install pillow --upgrade
```

Pillow version 10.2.0 was installed and solved my error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a good suggestion, though I would use `pip3 install --user ...` instead of `sudo pip3 install ...` whenever possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-of-pip-install-user) for more info.