# Import error while running Python script as Azure webjob

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I'm trying to run a python script as an Azure webjob on App service. I have packaged the script along with required libraries using virtualenv. Still I'm getting import error.

```
File "D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\get-stock-details\03j5dtql.crz\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
from .. import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'
```

I though of installing pip and the libraries directly using Kudu console, but there I'm getting Access denied error.

I'm using Python 3.6 and Windows as my OS.

Comment: I'm yet to test it. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

> I though of installing pip and the libraries directly using Kudu console, but there I'm getting Access denied error.

I can reproduce the issue, you can use the [`--user`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user) parameter, then the error will not appear.

```
python -m pip install <package-name> --user
```