# Why do my pip installations require 'python -m install --user'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am running this inside a virtual environment.

When I type:

`pip install django`

I get:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
> 13] Permission denied: /home/ENV/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz
> Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.

For it to work, I actually need to input:

`python -m pip install --user django`

Why?

Comment: What Are You Using Window or Mac And Linux?

Comment: if you are using windows window don't allow python to install django

Comment: if you give me os name i will give you answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

Comment: @SundeepPidugu not really, you forgot the `python -m` part

Comment: @RMPR Both of them work just fine. You can either use `pip` or `pip3` while running.

Comment: This question also have his own importance because `python -m` is here to specify the interpreter, you must not neglect that, if you have multiple versions of python installed, keeping track of which python version version pip is bound to is a PITA imo, hence `python -m` in this case you're sure that it's the pip bound to the python called which will be executed.

Comment: So it's a combination of [what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch) and your question.

Comment: Got it @RMPR thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break the two statements you added to your first command:
`python -m install --user django`

- `python -m`: Allows modules to be located using the Python module namespace for execution as scripts. The motivating examples were standard library modules such as pdb and profile. See [PEP 338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/)
- `--user` : By default pip installs Python packages to system directories which requires root privileges, to avoid using `sudo pip install` (which is not recommended by the way) use this flag to make pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.

As a side note, if you have multiple versions of Python installed, keeping track of which Python version version pip is bound to can be a PITA, hence `python -m` in this case you're sure that it's the pip bound to the Python called which will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to install the package to a system folder which you don't have permissions to write to. And the option `--user` allows to install it to user folder, where you do have rights (*[[Errno 13] Permission denied. How do I solve this problem? #236](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/236)*).

Answer (score 0):

The error basically states that you do not have permissions to write files to your machine, so if you are a root user (or administrator) you can always install Python packages with:

`sudo pip install django`

Or

`pip install --user django`

`--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.