# Error while running python code on EC2 server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

HI I am trying to run my python codes from EC2 server. the connection and all has been completed so that works fine. however when I try and run a code it gave me an error 
`ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'`
Tried to install matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib` but I get an error `` ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions. ``

Comment: you aren't allowed do `sudo pip install`? It works in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip defaults to installing Python packages to a system directory (such as /usr/local/lib/python3.4). This requires root access.

--user makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.

reference: [What is the purpose "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

Comment: thanks @hithyshi, that was helpful. I tried downloading using ```sudo pip3 --user install matplotlib```, but get another error   ```File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'``` any idea what's happening here?

Comment: @PrasKam try this: python3 -m pip install --user "packagename"  and let me know

Comment: perfect, thanks @hithyshi, that was very helpful again. its working fine now

Comment: although one issue I just realised is that I don't see my graphs when I run it from the EC2 server. something that you are aware of?