# Using Jinja2 in gitlab Ci pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, jinja2, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

Create a GitLab pipeline that personalizes emails using a Jinja2 template and a YAML file containing recipient information. The pipeline should take in two source files, one for the template and one for the recipient data (an array of recipients in a variables file (YAML)), process them with the jinja2docker package, and output a single file with the personalized emails for each recipient. The processed files should be pushed to Git and the output file should be saved as an artifact.

```
My problem is:
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/caisin/Emails/.git/
Checking out d384984e as master...
**Removing jinja2docker/**
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Using docker image sha256:5288c9cee5f00fb66c0bb5301e594218c3670ecccd8cbf64d82248fa1e79264c for gitlab.fit.cvut.cz:5000/ict/images/alpine/ci:latest with digest gitlab.fit.cvut.cz:5000/ict/images/alpine/ci@sha256:98530a57e266169dc6bcfc716c340bdd39705fe2ca48b5fbf1c600c88ad4657b ...
**/bin/sh: eval: line 141: jinja2: not found**
$ if [ -n "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" ] && [ "${CI_BUILD_STAGE#deploy}" != "$CI_BUILD_STAGE" ]; then # collapsed multi-line command
$ echo "Processing template and variables using Jinja2..."
Processing template and variables using Jinja2...
$ jinja2 $TEMPLATE_FILE $VARIABLES_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FILE
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01 
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

```
variables:
  TEMPLATE_FILE: email_template.html
  VARIABLES_FILE: recipient_data.yml
  OUTPUT_FILE: output.txt

prepare:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - echo "Preparing files for processing..."
    - git clone https://github.com/dinuta/jinja2docker.git
    - echo "Jinja2 repository cloned and ready for use."

process:
  stage: process
  script:
    - echo "Processing template and variables using Jinja2..."
    - jinja2 $TEMPLATE_FILE $VARIABLES_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FILE
    - echo "Processing complete!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -n "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" ] && [ "${CI_BUILD_STAGE#deploy}" != "$CI_BUILD_STAGE" ]; then # collapsed multi-line command
```

was listed in your output, while no line in `gitlab-ci.yml` mentioned. Anyway looks like the question is not in GitLab CI and `gitlab-ci.yml` file, but execution of your jinja-related command: is it installed and runs properly under `gitlab-runner` user because (again from your output):

```
**/bin/sh: eval: line 141: jinja2: not found**
```

You can check:

```
$ su - gitlab-runner
$ TEMPLATE_FILE='email_template.html' ; \
  VARIABLES_FILE='recipient_data.yml' ; \
  'OUTPUT_FILE='output.txt'; \
  jinja2 $TEMPLATE_FILE $VARIABLES_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FILE; \
  echo $?
```

Is your python version installed under user or it's system? Sometimes python site-packages might not be visible under user. This way you could find your default python (e.g. [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu)) reinstall your jinja using `--user` key (see [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-of-pip-install-user) question).

Also check your `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH` variables under `gitlab-runner` user.

When your command `python` (or `python3`) becomes available to `gitlab-runner` user you can exectute your jinja call like:

```
# Install jinja2 package
$ python3 -m pip install jinja2  # or add --user key for user site*packages
# Try to run jinja2 directly to get an error
$ python3 -m jinja2 $TEMPLATE_FILE $VARIABLES_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FILE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
/usr/bin/python3: No module named jinja2.__main__; 'jinja2' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

So you could use jinja like:

```
python3 -c "import jinja2; ... your jinja-related python code here"
```

or [use j2cli](https://medium.com/linuxstories/j2cli-templating-shell-scripts-355589b38a77) wrapper.