# What are user and global installations when in a conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am trying to update pip within my conda environment using pip install --upgrade pip. However, I am getting this warning message: "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"

What does user and global refer to when I am already within a conda environment?

Comment: `pip` itself can install to a global location or a per-user location (`~/.local`), independent of whether you are using a virtual environment of any kind. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42988977/1126841

Comment: Catching the inability of `pip install ...` to write to the global location and automatically running `pip install --user ...` appears to be Conda-specific.

Comment: Conda environments that you own should never result in this error. Either you don't have `pip` installed in the environment or the environment is not properly activated. Moreover, I would strongly discourage updating the `pip` in a Conda environment with `pip`. Even if you are using `pip` for all other packages, Conda should be used for exactly `python` and `pip` updates.

Comment: @chepner "*...appears to be Conda-specific.*" - how do you conclude that? That behavior is [in the official source](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/0ad4c94be74cc24874c6feb5bb3c2152c398a18e/src/pip/_internal/commands/install.py#L707-L717), i.e., any Python installation will behave like this if the `site-packages` is not writable. Conda environments are writable by default, so I'd expect it more likely that `pip` here isn't in a Conda environment. Would help to see a `which pip`.

Comment: @merv Has that always been true? (Granted, it's been years and years since I tried to use `pip` outside a virtual environment, but I thought I remembered `pip` failing when the target was unwritable.)

Comment: @chepner looks like that messaging has been there 5 years, and prior to that the code seems to still fall back to user site, just silently. However, if you're using `venv`, it explicitly sets `ENABLE_USER_SITE: False` as part of the environment, which Conda doesn't do. Perhaps that's the difference you're identifying? I.e., with a `venv` environment, lack of permissions to update in the site-packages should just fail since the user site is not considered.